# Border Line Increasing Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

border-collapse when zoom border size increase and i cant able to apply internal and external css because i want to send table in mail
Thanks In Advance
CSRIT

I Try Rules Attribute And Border Collapse

Comment: So, can you show us the code, which you tried?

Comment: This may help you put code into your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.